# Filter a measure in Power Pivot

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I'm trying to group the far right column based on the (top 5/ all the rest) of the rank column. I need a result where I can display a chart that shows the aggregated 'number of sales' for the (top 5/all the rest)

Here is an example:

[image]

I'm using RANKX to rank based on the 'Units sold', and using an if statement to segment into a yes/no.

How do I aggregate this further so I can find the total units sold for YES and total units sold for NO? I need to keep this in the pivottable. I'm thinking of adding a measure that can be used as a filter or aggregation but I can't add measures to filter. I just started with DAX and I might be missing something.

Comment: Please provide your DAX to better understand your case.

Comment: I first use Rankx to rank the units sold 

RANKING: =RANKX(ALL(Range[UNIT]),[Distinct Count of UNITS SOLD]).

Then I use an If statement to categorize further:

=IF([RANKING]<=5, "yes", "no")

Comment: Check this out..                                                                                                
Top 5 = IF(RANKX(ALL(Range[UNIT]),[Distinct Count of UNITS SOLD])<= 5 , "YES","NO")

UNITSOLD = SUM(UNITS SOLD)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a straight list of items with a total at the bottom, you could do this:

assume the table is called 'data':

--

Calculated Columns:

isTop5 = if(rankx(all(data),data[units])<=5,1,0) -- top five gets a 1, everything else 0

--

Measures:

numTopFive:=sum([isTop5])  -- add up your top fives (maybe your population only had 4 lines?)

numNotTop5:=count([code])-[numTopFive]  -- subtract number of top 5s from total population count

--

-However-

If you try to subgroup this (i.e. group your codes into regions), then the example I provided will not show five top-5s for each subgroup, it will only show the sum of top 5s if a particular code so happened to be in the top 5 of the entire population.   hopefully that makes sense.  If you need this using sub-grouping I can provide a different example.